# Sum for the last 5 records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sum

Table `StockSession` columns:

```
IdSeq, IdStock, DateSession, ChangePercent
```

[image: screenshot]

How can I get the sum of the `ChangePercent` column of the last five rows grouped by `IdStock`?

Comment: Please do not upload images here for the [reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) outlined in the link. p.s. welcome to the forum!

Answer (score 2):

Using a common table expression to assign a [row number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and partitioning by `IdStock` and ordering by `DateSession` desc, we're able to sum up `PercentChange` and group by `IdStock` where the row number is <= 5

```
--demo setup
Declare @StockSession table (IdSeq int, IdStock int, DateSession date, ChangePercent decimal(11,2))
insert into @StockSession(IdSeq,IdStock,DateSession,ChangePercent) values
(1,1,'2019-01-01',1),
(2,1,'2019-02-01',2),
(3,1,'2019-03-01',3),
(4,1,'2019-04-01',4),
(5,1,'2019-05-01',5),
(6,1,'2019-06-01',6),
(7,2,'2019-01-01',10),
(8,2,'2019-02-01',20),
(9,2,'2019-03-01',30),
(10,2,'2019-04-01',40),
(11,2,'2019-05-01',50),
(12,2,'2019-06-01',60)

----------
--solution
;

WITH _cte
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY IdStock ORDER BY DateSession DESC
            ) AS rn
    FROM @StockSession
    )
SELECT IdStock
    ,sum(ChangePercent) as SumChangePercent
FROM _cte
WHERE rn <= 5
GROUP BY IdStock
```

---

```
| IdStock | SumChangePercent |
|---------|------------------|
| 1       | 20.00            |
| 2       | 200.00           |
```

Comment: Awesome !!!!!!Thanks a LOT !!!!!!